# Эффективное вычисление факториала

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Дано два алгоритма вычисления факториала на c++:

> !6
>
> 1 * 2 * 3 * 4 *
>   5 * 6

```
!6    
       720
 2   *  12  *  30
1 * 2  3 * 4  5 * 6
```

Говорят что второй алгоритм быстрей из за дерева множителей, почему суммарно умножение равных по размеру чисел быстрей? Как умножаются числа в компьютере в двоичном коде - знаю. 
PS: Во втором алгоритме не задействована многопоточность.

UPDATE: Нашел статью http://habrahabr.ru/post/255761/

Comment: Вот кто так говорит, пусть и приведет свои аргументы. Обращайтесь к автору этого утверждения.

Comment: Иногда на одном процессорном конвейере могут выполняться одновременно несколько инструкций одновременно. Кроме того, в программируемой логике второй способ будет однозначно быстрее работать.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow http://habrahabr.ru/post/255761/

Comment: @relaxGalaxy Вопрос задан здесь, а потому необходимо обосновать в вопросе утверждения, а не делать ссылки на разные сайты. Иначе вопрос не понятен.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow я хочу узнать почему из за дерева множителей алгоритм выполняется быстрей, не понимаю вас. Я нашел статью в которой этот алгоритм описан, я описал главную часть в вопросе.

Comment: @relaxGalaxy  Я не вижу ни одного обоснования, почему вы так решили. Совершенно бессмысленный вопрос.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow так говорят люди и люди в статье, а я понять не могу почему. Вы можете отредактировать мой вопрос, вам видней.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow "Для N=50 000 факториал вычисляется за 0,9 секунд, что почти вдвое быстрее, чем в наивной реализации." Даже в статье говорят об его эффективности.

Comment: @relaxGalaxy Покажите эти реализации двух алгоритмов для N = 50000, и обоснуйте, как это связано с самими алгоритмами. а не с их реализациями.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, посмотрите мот ответ. Дело и правда в асимптотике самих алгоритмов.

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov  С моей точки зрения это все пустые рассуждения, так как нет реализаций алгоритмов.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, когда один алгоритм превосходит другой асимптотически - от реализации зависит лишь на каком порядке исходных данных это превосходство проявится. Причем если различие в асимптотике достаточно сильное - то даже самая плохая (но корректная) реализация не сможет все сильно испортить.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Речь идет о так называемой "длинной арифметике", когда числа перестают влазить в разрядную сетку и представляются в виде массива байт. Конкретно при вычислении 6! никаких отличий в двух алгоритмах нет - они проявляются при вычислении 1000!.

Длина числа N! - это O(log N!) = O(N log N). Обозначим ее через L.

Первый алгоритм работает за время порядка 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + L (всего N слагаемых) - ведь умножение длинного числа на короткое занимает время порядка длины длинного числа. Общее время - O(NL) = O(N<sup>2</sup> log N)

Второй алгоритм "в лоб" работает за время порядка 1 * N + 4 * N/2 + 16 * N/4 + ... + L<sup>2</sup>. Здесь общий член ряда - это время, необходимое для умножения двух чисел, ограниченных величиной O(N<sup>2<sup>i</sup></sup>) (длина такого числа - это L = O(2<sup>i</sup> log N)), умноженное на число таких умножений (это N/2<sup>i</sup>)

Поскольку умножение наивным методом работает за O(L<sup>2</sup>) - общий член ряда равен O((2<sup>i</sup>log N)<sup>2</sup> N/2<sup>i</sup>) = O(2<sup>i</sup> N log<sup>2</sup> N) Сумма такого ряда является геометрической прогрессией и асимптотически равна старшему члену ряда.

Поэтому весь алгоритм работает за такое же время, которое требуется для последнего, завершающего умножения - это время O(L<sup>2</sup>) = O(N<sup>2</sup> log<sup>2</sup> N). Это даже медленнее, чем первый алгоритм!

Но все меняется, если использовать [алгоритм Карацубы](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0#.D0.A3.D0.BC.D0.BD.D0.BE.D0.B6.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.B5_.D0.9A.D0.B0.D1.80.D0.B0.D1.86.D1.83.D0.B1.D1.8B), который работает за время O(L<sup>log<sub>2</sub>3</sup>). Как и в прошлый раз, старший член ряда задоминирует все остальные - и нам необходимо думать лишь о самом последнем умножении. И это умножение займет время O((N log N)<sup>log<sub>2</sub>3</sup>) = O(N<sup>log<sub>2</sub>3</sup> log<sup>log<sub>2</sub>3</sup> N), что меньше O(N<sup>2</sup> log N), необходимых для первого алгоритма.

---

Краткий вывод: при наивной реализации первый алгоритм работает быстрее второго. Но использование методик быстрого умножения длинных чисел дает преимущество второму методу.

Преимущество второго алгоритма над первым обусловлено тем фактом, что во втором алгоритме все умножения, кроме самого последнего, выполняются очень быстро (по сравнению с последним), в то время как в первом алгоритме такого "бонуса" нет.

Comment: Можете объяснить это равенство в правой части? O(log N!) = O(N log N) Это так преобразовали в худшую неточную оценку относительно двоичного кода? PS: Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Это асимптотическая оценка факториала по формуле Стирлинга. И она, вообще-то, точная.

Comment: Подробнее - читайте Википедию, статью _"«O» большое и «o» малое"_

Comment: "Отношение (ln n!) к (n ln n − n) стремится к 1 с увеличением n" почему тогда - n отбросили?

Comment: Потому что O(N ln N - N) = O(N log N). И даже в обратную сторону это тоже верно. Говорю же, прочитайте что такое "О большое".

Answer (score 1):

Наоборот, второй алгоритм не поможет, потому что надо сохранить `n/2` результатов и сделать `n-1` умножений. Первый алгоритм только требует сохранение одного результата, и количество умножений то же самое.

Есть очень быстрый вариант, если надо вычислить факториал много раз: сохранить всех нужных результатов в массиве. Например, если используете [числа двойной точности](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8), только надо сохранять первые 170 результатов (остальные уже слишком большие). Вот так:

```js
var factorials = [1,1,2,6,24,120,720,5040,40320,362880,3628800,39916800,479001600,6227020800,87178291200,1307674368000,20922789888000,355687428096000,6402373705728000,121645100408832000,2432902008176640000,51090942171709440000,1.1240007277776077e+21,2.585201673888498e+22,6.204484017332394e+23,1.5511210043330986e+25,4.0329146112660565e+26,1.0888869450418352e+28,3.0488834461171384e+29,8.841761993739701e+30,2.6525285981219103e+32,8.222838654177922e+33,2.631308369336935e+35,8.683317618811886e+36,2.9523279903960412e+38,1.0333147966386144e+40,3.719933267899012e+41,1.3763753091226343e+43,5.23022617466601e+44,2.0397882081197442e+46,8.159152832478977e+47,3.3452526613163803e+49,1.4050061177528798e+51,6.041526306337383e+52,2.6582715747884485e+54,1.1962222086548019e+56,5.5026221598120885e+57,2.5862324151116818e+59,1.2413915592536073e+61,6.082818640342675e+62,3.0414093201713376e+64,1.5511187532873822e+66,8.065817517094388e+67,4.2748832840600255e+69,2.308436973392414e+71,1.2696403353658276e+73,7.109985878048635e+74,4.052691950487722e+76,2.350561331282879e+78,1.3868311854568986e+80,8.320987112741392e+81,5.075802138772248e+83,3.146997326038794e+85,1.98260831540444e+87,1.2688693218588417e+89,8.247650592082472e+90,5.443449390774431e+92,3.647111091818868e+94,2.4800355424368305e+96,1.711224524281413e+98,1.197857166996989e+100,8.504785885678622e+101,6.123445837688608e+103,4.4701154615126834e+105,3.3078854415193856e+107,2.480914081139539e+109,1.8854947016660498e+111,1.4518309202828584e+113,1.1324281178206295e+115,8.946182130782973e+116,7.156945704626378e+118,5.797126020747366e+120,4.75364333701284e+122,3.945523969720657e+124,3.314240134565352e+126,2.8171041143805494e+128,2.4227095383672724e+130,2.107757298379527e+132,1.8548264225739836e+134,1.6507955160908452e+136,1.4857159644817607e+138,1.3520015276784023e+140,1.24384140546413e+142,1.1567725070816409e+144,1.0873661566567424e+146,1.0329978488239052e+148,9.916779348709491e+149,9.619275968248206e+151,9.426890448883242e+153,9.33262154439441e+155,9.33262154439441e+157,9.425947759838354e+159,9.614466715035121e+161,9.902900716486175e+163,1.0299016745145622e+166,1.0813967582402903e+168,1.1462805637347078e+170,1.2265202031961373e+172,1.3246418194518284e+174,1.4438595832024928e+176,1.5882455415227421e+178,1.7629525510902437e+180,1.9745068572210728e+182,2.2311927486598123e+184,2.543559733472186e+186,2.925093693493014e+188,3.3931086844518965e+190,3.969937160808719e+192,4.6845258497542883e+194,5.574585761207603e+196,6.689502913449124e+198,8.09429852527344e+200,9.875044200833598e+202,1.2146304367025325e+205,1.5061417415111404e+207,1.8826771768889254e+209,2.372173242880046e+211,3.012660018457658e+213,3.8562048236258025e+215,4.9745042224772855e+217,6.466855489220472e+219,8.471580690878817e+221,1.118248651196004e+224,1.4872707060906852e+226,1.992942746161518e+228,2.6904727073180495e+230,3.659042881952547e+232,5.01288874827499e+234,6.917786472619486e+236,9.615723196941086e+238,1.346201247571752e+241,1.89814375907617e+243,2.6953641378881614e+245,3.8543707171800706e+247,5.550293832739301e+249,8.047926057471987e+251,1.17499720439091e+254,1.7272458904546376e+256,2.5563239178728637e+258,3.808922637630567e+260,5.7133839564458505e+262,8.627209774233235e+264,1.3113358856834518e+267,2.006343905095681e+269,3.089769613847349e+271,4.789142901463391e+273,7.47106292628289e+275,1.1729568794264138e+278,1.8532718694937338e+280,2.946702272495037e+282,4.714723635992059e+284,7.590705053947215e+286,1.2296942187394488e+289,2.0044015765453015e+291,3.2872185855342945e+293,5.423910666131586e+295,9.003691705778433e+297,1.5036165148649983e+300,2.526075744973197e+302,4.2690680090047027e+304,7.257415615307994e+306];
alert(factorials[18]);
```

Comment: http://habrahabr.ru/post/255761/ Нашел еще статью с описанием. Они тестировали этот алгоритм, говорят быстрей.

Comment: @Peter Olson Не ясно, чему вы оппонируете, так как в вопросе нет никаких аргументов. Бессмысленный вопрос и такой же бессмысленный ответ.